# How do I output the list of allocated memory buffers at any time when my software was compiled with AddressSanitizer?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

I'm looking at a problem with one of my daemons which is very memory hungry. It looks like certain parts never release memory even though when I make that daemon quit cleanly, there are no leaks.

I'd like to see what buffers get added and kept around while the daemon is running. Since I already compile with the `-fsanitizer=address` command line option, I would imagine I have access to some function that can do that?

I thought I saw a "libasan", but I was not able to find any documentation about it. Isn't there such a thing? If there is, where is that documentation?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this with asan, but It would be cool though. I would recommend to use massif.

Comment: @mkaes Ah. I looked into massif and generated a table. Easy enough to run my daemon. The output seems to say that there are no leaks though... even while running. There is another question with my results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618504

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to dump Asan memory allocation statistics. With recent Asan versions you can check for memory leaks by running with `export ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1` but I don't think this is the cause of your problem.

Your problem may be caused by Asan quarantine - Asan does not immediately deallocate memory on `free` to be able to report use-after-free errors. Default quarantine size is 256M, you can control it via `export ASAN_OPTIONS=quarantine_size_mb=16`.

BTW note that compiling production version of your SW with `-fsanitize=address` is not recommended (Asan is meant for error detection, not prevention).

Comment: Ah, good to know that we can limit the quarantine. Also I have a test system that runs my production version where I can have the sanitizer turned on. I never ran it on my live system! :-)

Comment: @AlexisWilke (y)